# How to sum rows and columns in r?

Tags: r, gis

How do I sum the following table? I have many more columns starting with "cumul". I would like to sum both by row and column.There after plotting a line graph with the sum data.

I need help in ploting graph to extract the relevant information from the data table too.

```
        CVE_ENT              NOMGEO Pop2016 cumul13 cumul14 cumul15 cumul16   
## 1       09           Azcapotzalco  408441      19      46      87     156  
## 2       09               Coyoacán  621952      25      44     107     213  
## 3       09  Cuajimalpa de Morelos  199809      66      75      93     122  


Sum Column and Group By Expected Results
CVE_ENT cumul13total cumul14total cumul15total cumul16total
09        129           165             287        491
15        465           764             123        365

Sum Row & Group By Expected Results
CVE_ENT  Total
09        298
15        567


# Edited code:
#group by and column sum
result1 <- sf_MC %>%
            group_by(CVE_ENT) %>%
            summarise(across(starts_with('cumu'), sum, na.rm = TRUE, 
                      .names = '{col}_total'))
dput(result1)

Extracted Result using  dput(result1) :

    structure(list(CVE_ENT = c("09", "15", "17"), cumul13_total = c(493, 
## 252, 13), cumul14_total = c(918, 540, 31), cumul15_total = c(1727, 
## 1059, 65), cumul16_total = c(3358, 2141, 126), cumul17_total = c(5920, 
## 3844, 303), cumul18_total = c(8916, 5869, 551), cumul19_total = c(13080, 
## 8414, 872), cumul20_total = c(18212, 11818, 1196),.....cumul13_total = NA_integer_, cumul14_total = NA_integer_, cumul15_total = NA_integer_, 
    ## cumul16_total = NA_integer_, cumul17_total = NA_integer_, cumul18_total = NA_integer_, 
    ## cumul19_total = NA_integer_, class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", 
## "aggregate", "identity")))
```

Comment: Edited for expected result

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
library(dplyr)

#group by and column sum
result1 <- sf_MC %>%
            group_by(CVE_ENT) %>%
            summarise(across(starts_with('cumu'), sum, na.rm = TRUE, 
                      .names = '{col}_total'))


#rowwise sum
result2 <- cbind(result1[1], total = rowSums(result1[-1]))
```

Comment: I received the following error. What do this error mean? 

Error in base:: rowSums (x...):'x' must be numeric calls

Comment: @Lawrence It means the data we are trying to sum is not numeric. When do you get this error? While running step1 or step2 ?

Comment: Do you have `data.table` ? Try with. : `result2 <- cbind(result1[, 1], total = rowSums(result1[, -1]))` Or else can you provide `dput(result1)` ?

Comment: The step 1 doesn't seem like it output as data.table.  how do I go about doing that?

dput(result1) shows "structure(list(..."

Comment: Can you edit your post to include `dput` ooutput of `result1` ?

Comment: Added in the results of dput(result1) above.

Comment: @Lawrence Your `dput` output returns a list in `result1`. Do you list as output?

Comment: I had a came out a walkaround method last night: "sum(c_across(where(is.numeric)))". May I know how to you group all the column names starting with "cumul" into a group in order to use as y axis to plot the line graph.

Comment: You can use `starts_with('cumul')` to get all those columns.